# Is there a way to have a fast upload to an S3 AWS bucket from a web form?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, post

I'm currently working to find a solution that let people upload to an s3 bucket from a web form with a relative high speed.
I've tried already with a couple of nodejs libraries ([evaporatejs](https://github.com/TTLabs/EvaporateJS) and [resumablejs](https://github.com/23/resumable.js/)) but it's kinda low on upload speed (~3.5 MB/s) and with the [signedUrl PUT request solution](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-s3-presigned-urls-aws-sam), also very slow (~2 MB/s).
The point is, people should be able to upload to this bucket from all over the world, and we talk files that ranges from ~50MB to a couple GBs, so it's necessary that the speed is considerably high as i don't want a 30 minutes upload.

I was wondering if anyone knows a better way to achieve the goal cuz i've looked around for a week and found only these, but they're not enough.

All answers will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at AWS S3 Multipart uploads? Multipart uploads are seriously quick.

Comment: Well, i used the multipart POST request. just searched on google your answer and found out that are 2 different type of upload. thank you @Anss, gonna try that asap.

Answer (score 0):

Along with multipart upload, try out s3 transfer acceleration. With transfer acceleration, client data will be loaded to the nearest edge location, and from there it will go to your S3 bucket. It can improve your performance anywhere from 10 to 50%.

S3 transfer acceleration - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/transfer-acceleration.html

There is one drawback of this approach. For clients who are near to S3 bucket location, it adds extra hop to move data from client to S3. But that is a small penalty compared to the overall advantage of using S3 transfer acceleration.

S3 transfer acceleration speed comparison - http://s3-accelerate-speedtest.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/en/accelerate-speed-comparsion.html

[image: S3 Transfer acceleration demo]

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. I've tried this but unfortunately the output is still the same and the upload is very slow.